# Copy all the poses over the animation

Tags: animation, rigging

I had an animation for a rigged bone that I made with a mirror modifier because the same rig had to be mirrored. But .fbx export for unity applies the modifier and the rig was not as expected.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I have about 20 frames of animation and almost 12 bones, I just showed one for sample. If I do everything manually I'll have to iterate 240 times. How can I copy all the animation from one set of bones to another?

**EDIT: **The final mesh also needs to be a single object(mesh).